# Random Number doesn't change in for loop

Tags: javascript, code.org

I have a for loop that draws lines in a certain direction. In the for loop, I want to change the color of the line using random numbers. But for some reason it doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
  random1 = randomNumber(0, 255);
  random2 = randomNumber(0, 255);
  random3 = randomNumber(0, 255);
  
  stroke(rgb(random1, random2, random3));
  liftUp();
  backward(100);
  turnLeft(45);
  forward(200);
  random1 = randomNumber(0, 255);
  random2 = randomNumber(0, 255);
  random3 = randomNumber(0, 255);
  
  stroke(rgb(random1, random2, random3));
  liftDown();
  backward(150);
  turnRight(45);
  forward(150);
  turnRight(135);
  forward(150);
}
```

Comment: What are the functions used?

Comment: What does that randomNumber function do? can you provide details on what you've tried? If its a custom function, provide randomNumber function code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*not sure, but that's my analyze*

You're using the same variable, `random1, 2, 3` to draw two different line.

I do not know how `stroke()` should draw your line, but since you're changing `random1, 2, 3` to then reuse them into the second `stroke()` method you'll change the reference of the first stroke, which may result on draying twice the same line.

+ you seems to be declaring this variable outside the for loop.

What may be a quick fix could be the following

**Edit: you can use either the first or second `randomNumber()` function below taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-whole-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range)**

```js
/**
 * Returns a random number between min (inclusive) and max (exclusive)
 */
function randomNumber(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

/**
 * Returns a random integer between min (inclusive) and max (inclusive).
 * The value is no lower than min (or the next integer greater than min
 * if min isn't an integer) and no greater than max (or the next integer
 * lower than max if max isn't an integer).
 * Using Math.round() will give you a non-uniform distribution!
 */
function randomNumber(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
  
  stroke(rgb(randomNumber(0, 255), randomNumber(0, 255), randomNumber(0, 255)));
  liftUp();
  backward(100);
  turnLeft(45);
  forward(200);
  
  stroke(rgb(randomNumber(0, 255), randomNumber(0, 255), randomNumber(0, 255)));
  liftDown();
  backward(150);
  turnRight(45);
  forward(150);
  turnRight(135);
  forward(150);
}
```

Didn't test it, but this is the only logical way of solving your problem.

Comment: This is not how JavaScript works. Primitives are not passed to a function by reference, they are just copied. Your explanation is wrong.

Comment: Thx @YuriyYakym I did remove the explanation to avoid any misleading. Could you explain me why the code wasn't working then ? I'll update my answer then

Answer (score 0):

I like @Raphael Balet's start, but I would edit a little farther.  I'm assuming your using `liftUp()` like `penUp()`([API](https://studio.code.org/docs/applab/penUp/)) and `liftDown()` like `penDown()` in *AppLab*

For general reference here is Code.org's `randomNumber()` [API](https://studio.code.org/docs/applab/randomNumber_min_max/)

**Old Code with Comments**

```
for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
  stroke(rgb(randomNumber(0, 255), randomNumber(0, 255), randomNumber(0, 255)));
  //since lifting up no line drawn till pen placed back down
  liftUp();
  //So this code does nothing but reposition pen (so color #1 never seen :-(  )
  backward(100);
  turnLeft(45);
  forward(200);
  
  //New color
  stroke(rgb(randomNumber(0, 255), randomNumber(0, 255), randomNumber(0, 255)));
  //Pen down so will see output
  liftDown();
  backward(150);
  turnRight(45);
  forward(150);
  turnRight(135);
  forward(150);
}
```

**New Code**

```
for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
  //reposition pen, needed?
  backward(100);
  turnLeft(45);
  forward(200);

  //Set Color
  var r = randomNumber(0, 255);
  var g = randomNumber(0, 255);
  var b = randomNumber(0, 255);
  stroke(rgb(r, g, b));

  //lower drawing implement
  liftDown();
  //Drive!
  backward(150);
  turnRight(45);
  forward(150);
  turnRight(135);
  forward(150);
}
```